# Error calling php file for a dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a drop down menu that queries information in a mysql database. I've got that working and now with help from @jeroen I think I now have it passing the object selected to the namesearch16.php. The webpage is located here:
http://swapabook.hostei.com/search16.php

There are no errors but I was expecting it to output the lines in the database that matched the query.

I'm returned with string:
array(1) { ["select1"]=> &string(4) "book" }

I have a feeling that the problem is my while statement that I am returning the wrong thing. By the way my table has 5 fields of which I want to return 4 of them something like select book, author, genre, email from book

Initial file has code as follows:

```
<form action="namesearch16.php" method="post">
Name of Book
<?php
mysql_connect("mysql1x.000webhost.com","a4425533_swapabo","xxxxx") or      die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db('a4425533_swapabo')or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "SELECT * FROM book";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="select1">
<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['book'];?>"> <?php echo $line['book'];?> </option> 
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Changed second file to following as per inputs from @jeroen:

```
<?php
      $con=mysqli_connect('mysql1x.000webhost.com','a4425533_swapabo','xxxx','a4425533_swapabo');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$namequery="SELECT * FROM book WHERE book = ?";
$namestmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $namequery);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($namestmt, "s", $_POST['select1']);
var_dump($_POST);

mysqli_stmt_execute($namestmt);

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $namequery)) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['book'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo "got as far as the while loop";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Next time it would be very helpful, if you would post the error message and the desired behavior.

Comment: You really should use a prepared statement and not just dump user input straight in the query.

Comment: I added extra info to the question above. Sorry for the confusion:

Comment: I'm trying to create a drop down menu that queries information in a mysql database. I've got that working but it doesn't seem to be passing the object selected to the namesearch10.php. The webpage is located here:
http://swapabook.hostei.com/search10.php

There are no errors but I was expecting it to output the lines in the database that matched the query.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` does not appear to have an `book` element, so you would need to change:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM book WHERE book = '$_POST[book]'");
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM book WHERE book = '$_POST[select1]'");
```

**However**, you need to make sure you don't have an sql injection problem, so your query should really look like:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE book = ?
```

Then you prepare the query and bind the `$_POST['select1']` value to it, see for example [this section in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

**Edit:** Your edit has a few problems (apart from the typos...): Just follow the steps [from the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php):

- don't quote your `$_POST` variable: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($namestmt, "s", $_POST['select1']);`
- execute the query;
- bind the results;
- fetch the result set.

And you need to get rid of this line as that would mean doing another query to the database:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$namequery);
```

Comment: I updated my code above. Any chance you could look to see if I've made an obvious mistake.

Comment: @daithi_dearg More than a few, see my edit, but great you are switching to a prepared statement :-)

Comment: I think I have corrected what you suggested. Any ideas on the last hurdle?

Comment: @daithi_dearg You are still doing 2 queries, the `mysqli_stmt_execute` one and the `mysqli_query` one.

Comment: I had tried previously with this query removed "if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $namequery))" but I was getting errors and I couldn't really figure out what I should be passing to mysqli_fetch_array(). My best guess was passing $namestmt but it didn't like that either. I know you may feel that I'm making very basic mistakes but I'm a bit lost as to what else I can try.